# Doctrine Select last record from second table matching with first table

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

[image]

I have tow tables, first table related to forms and second table relate to adviser.each adviser can add comment for a form.
I tried select some column of two tables. It was works i have  last subject of second table (**adviser table** ) in my result .but i need first subject of second table(**adviser table** ) .

```
#DQL
SELECT
    f.name,
    f.title,
    f.conditionResultFinal,
    f.conditionResult,
    f.formCode,
    f.dateInsert,
    f.id,
    (a.idFormRequestProject),
    a.subject as subjectAdvisor
FROM AdminBundle:FormRequestProject f
JOIN AdminBundle:Advisor a
WHERE a.idFormRequestProject = f.id
    AND (f.conditionResultFinal = 0 OR f.conditionResult = 0)
    AND f.displayStatus = 1
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER by a.id,f.id DESC
```

Comment: You have 2 WHERE clauses in your query. Could you please fix it and maybe improve the formatting while you are at it.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.i deleted second WHERE but no different .Again  my result is first comment of Advisor table.I updated my question

Comment: Could you add a minimal example with data, e.g. 3 rows with just id's, to show what result you get and which one you want? I'm guessing what you want is `ORDER BY a.id DESC, f.id DESC`, but I'm not sure if I understand the question right.

Comment: almost my question similer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989828/select-latest-record-from-right-table-when-using-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve this problem .i deleted **GROUP By** .and add new **where** ...

```
SELECT f.name,f.title,f.conditionResultFinal,
f.conditionResult ,
f.formCode,f.dateInsert ,
f.id,(a.idFormRequestProject),
a.subject as subjectAdvisor 
FROM AdminBundle:FormRequestProject f  
Left JOIN AdminBundle:Advisor a WHERE  f.id = a.idFormRequestProject AND a.id = 
(SELECT  Max (aa.id) FROM AdminBundle:Advisor aa WHERE a.idFormRequestProject = 
aa.idFormRequestProject ORDER by aa.id ASC )  AND 
(f.conditionResultFinal = 0 OR f.conditionResult = 0 ) AND  f.displayStatus =1   
ORDER by f.id DESC
```